# Could not able to retrieve distinct rows from a Column based on the condition of another column in SQL server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am new to SQL and I have a big table `my_table` having thousands of rows. The following is a sample:

```
 Id           JsonObject
  1           {"Pricing":{"PricingRule":Rule1}}
  1           {"Pricing":{"PricingRule":Rule2}}
  2           {"Pricing":{"PricingRule":Rule1}}
  3           {"Pricing":{"PricingRule":Rule4}}       
  3           {"Pricing":{"PricingRule":Rule1}}
  4           {"Pricing":{"PricingRule":Rule1}}
  4           {"Pricing":{"PricingRule":Rule9}}
  5           {"Pricing":{"PricingRule":Rule1}}
  6           {"Pricing":{"PricingRule":Rule10}}
```

What I want in the output is following:

```
 Id              JsonObject
  2              {"Pricing":{"PricingRule":Rule1}}
  5              {"Pricing":{"PricingRule":Rule1}}
```

Basically, I want the unique Ids which follow `PricingRule` as `Rule1` from the `JsonObject` column.
I tried the following code:

```
select Id, JsonObject  
from my_table 
where json_value(JsonObject, '$.Pricing.PricingRule') = 'Rule1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/afd145/5).

```
select
  Id,
  JsonObject
from
(
  select 
    *,
    count(*) over (partition by id) as total
  from Table1 
) val
where json_value(JsonObject, '$.Pricing.PricingRule') = 'Rule1'
and total = 1
```

Output:

```
*-----------------------------------------*
| Id      JsonObject                      |
*-----------------------------------------*
| 2   {"Pricing":{"PricingRule":"Rule1"}} |
| 5   {"Pricing":{"PricingRule":"Rule1"}} |
*-----------------------------------------*
```